# parametrizar sql en asp classic

Tags: sql, asp

Buenas,

Estoy haciendo una modificación de una web escrita en asp classic y necesito realizar cambios en esa web para implementar cierta seguridad hasta que pasemos a una versión más actual y una de las cosas que me han pedido es parametrizar las sql. El problema es que he estado haciendo pruebas y no he conseguido que logre devolverme ningún valor. El código que he creado es el siguiente:

```
    Set rs = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Conn.Open cab_db

    Set miCom = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set miCom.Activeconnection = Conn

    miCom.commandText="select valor as prueba from tabla1 where upper(valor) like '@pru' and valor2= pac_web.f_encriptapwd('@pru2') and fbaja is null"
    miCom.Parameters.Append miCom.CreateParameter("@pru",200,1 ,200,ucase(valorEntrada))
    miCom.Parameters.Append miCom.CreateParameter("@pru2",200,1 ,200,valorEntrada2)
    'response.write(param)
    'response.write(param1)

    response.write(miCom.commandText)
    'Response.Write("Llega")

    rs.Open miCom
    if not rs.eof then
        psperson = rs(0)
        response.write(psperson)
    end if
```

El problema que tengo es que no me devuelve ningún mensaje de error y no logro encontrar el fallo.
¿Alguien puede ayudarme?
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la consulta debes utilizar comillas simples cuando utilices constantes de cadena pero no para utilizar parámetros. Piensa en los parámetros como utilizarías una variable en tu código.

Con ADODB, además, no utilizarías parámetros con nombre en la consulta, sino marcadores de posición (?).

En lugar de:

```
 miCom.commandText="select valor as prueba from tabla1 where upper(valor) like '@pru' and valor2= pac_web.f_encriptapwd('@pru2') and fbaja is null"
```

Debería ser:

```
 miCom.commandText="select valor as prueba from tabla1 where upper(valor) like ? and valor2= pac_web.f_encriptapwd(?) and fbaja is null"
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias acabo de probar y me funciona